# Xcode; How to call function in AppDelegate from another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function, today-extension

I'm using `Swift` and the newest `Xcode` version.

I have this code in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func testPrint(string: String) {
    print(string)
}
```

I can successfully call the function from the file `ViewController.swift` like this:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.testPrint(string: "Hello!")
```

But if I'm trying to call the function from `TodayViewController.swift`, which is for Apples `Today Extension`, I'm getting the following error:

> Use of undeclared type 'AppDelegate'

Why that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along those lines:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.testPrint(string: "Hello!")
```

**EDIT**:
'Today Extension' and App live in a different contexts so it is not possible.

Comment: I'm getting `Use of undeclared type 'AppDelegate'`.

Comment: What version of Swift do you use?

Comment: If I'm trying to call the function with your code from `ViewController.swift` it's working. It's not working from `TodayViewController.swift` which is for Apples `Today Extension`. Any idea how? Is there something special if a file belongs to `Today Extension`?

Comment: show the whole code please

Comment: I updated my question. There isn't more code that matters for this case.

Comment: Ahh, 'Todays extension' is not an application so it does not have AppDelegate. What is it exactly you are trying to achieve? Why do you need the AppDelegate?

Comment: I have a function that I'm using in `AppDelegate.swift` multiple times. I need to call it once from `TodayViewController.swift`. If possible, I don't want to create the function in `TodayViewController.swift` again.

Comment: That's not possible... your app and the extension live in a different space...

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information.

Comment: Would be nice if you accepted my answer :)

Comment: Can you please mention the "information" in your answer?